# converting HTML4 websites to haskell with blaze-from-html

Tags: html, haskell, html4, blaze-html

I am trying to convert websites into the HTML data structure given by [`blaze`](http://jaspervdj.be/blaze/tutorial.html).

```
curl -S http://jaspervdj.be/blaze | blaze-from-html
```

This example is taken from the end of the `blaze-html` tutorial.  Curl obviously works, but this library can't build of the HTML

```
html $ do
    H.head $ H.title "301 Moved Permanently"
blaze-from-html: Attribute bgcolor is illegal in html5
```

Indeed, `bgcolor` has been [deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp).  How to I get blaze to run with HTML4?

---

```
curl -S http://jaspervdj.be/blaze | blaze-from-html -v html4-transitional
```

As suggested by the comments I used some transitional features and I get a [301](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301).  Does this page get redirected?

```
html $ do
    H.head $ H.title "301 Moved Permanently"
    body ! bgcolor "white" $ do
        center $ h1 "301 Moved Permanently"
        hr
        center "nginx/1.2.1"
```

However, `wget http://jaspervdj.be/blaze` returns the HTML content of the page.

Comment: You complete code is not included, so I don't know if you're already doing this, but import your functions from `Text.Blaze.Html4.*`?

Comment: Did you try piping to `blaze-from-html -v html4-transitional` instead of just `blaze-from-html` as the documentation you linked suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
curl -S http://jaspervdj.de/blaze | blaze-from-html -v html4-transitional
```

As suggested in the documentation you linked.

As for why one page is empty and says it's been redirected, it appears that curl sees a difference between `http://jaspervdj.de/blaze` and `http://jaspervdj.de/blaze/`, and the website you're downloading is erroneously treating them differently as well, while `wget` seems to automatically redirect like my browser does.  I would suggest contacting the website author and suggesting that he fix this behavior.

Comment: Yours works.  After reading about [pipes](http://serverfault.com/questions/25779/how-do-i-pipe-a-downloaded-file-to-standard-output-in-bash) I did `wget -O - http://jaspervdj.be/blaze | blaze-from-html -v html4-transitional`.

Comment: @johnmangual Good to know.  I took the liberty of emailing the maintainer of that website/library with this issue, hopefully it'll be resolved soon.